# Working with Time and TimeRange in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm starting a new project today. The application is a rewrite of an existing workscheduling application. The application works extensively with Times and TimeRanges.

Time: 08:45, 17:32, ... 
TimeRange: from 08:45 till 17:32

I started looking for a library that handles the plumbing for me with this kind of data, eg: Earlier than, later than, in between, etc. I found moment.js and date.js immediately. I feel however that these libraries are more concerned about a certain point in time (a JS Date object) rather than the above described notion of Time and TimeRange.

Does anyone have experience working with Time and TimeRange as I described above in a JavaScript environment? What library could be useful for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to compare dates. You can construct 2 dates and then compare using usual operator.

For an ex:

```
var date1 = new date();
var date2 = new date();
```

Then compare like `date1.getTime() == date2.getTime()` or whatever you want to compare.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have another look at [Moment JS](http://momentjs.com/docs/), it's probably what you need. It has a rich library of date handling functions, and uses Duration objects to represent time ranges.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.datejs.com and http://momentjs.com are the best as far as I'm concerned. A few more are listed here: http://codegeekz.com/6-javascript-date-libraries-for-developers/